# Не могу понять в чем отличия G2422 от G2412

Tags: железо, монитор, пк

Не могу понять в чем отличия G2422 от G2412. Смотрел спецификацию и сравнивал с разных магазинов, в том числе с сайта производителя, везде параметры одинаковые, но цена старшей модели значительно отличается, может кто подсказать в чем же всё таки отличия G2422 от G2412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSI G2412 and G2422 are identical. There are only minor differences in the width and weight of the model
[(c)](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/news/2509815)

Перевод с буржуйского: чуть-чуть тяжелее и шире.

Comment: Тогда почему такая огромная разница в цене?

Comment: хде именно?  у каждого продавана своя цена.  а ещё разные даты поставок, разный курс доллара.